# Using Google Map JavaScript library with cordova

Tags: javascript, cordova, google-maps

I am trying to use Google map JavaScript API with a cordova project,

I am getting the map, after few seconds, I am getting **RefererNotAllowedMapError** for file:///android_asset/www/index.html

I tried to provide this URL on the developer console also, but no luck.

I tried to provide wild card asterisk symbol

Is there any other way to set a custom referrer or how to solve this?

**---EDIT---**

I was using Browser API key, I changed to Android API key now it works fine.

**Wrong Value for cordova:** https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=<browser api key>

**Proper Value for cordova:** https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=<android api key>

Browser API key seems to be only allowed when the html page is executed on a http url

Comment: You have to use an API key from google for your app -> https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages But it is better to not use the javascript api in your app, use a native plugin. It is much more faster.

Comment: I am using an API key

Comment: Have you tried to recreate your API key?

Comment: Have you added your app in the Google developer settings?

Comment: I was using Browser API key, I changed to Android API key now it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

As of May 2017, the issue has been solved by Google. Now you can use file:/ referrers with API keys. You can see the following text in the documentation

`file:// referers need a special representation to be added to the Key restriction. The "file:/" part should be replaced with "__file_url__" before being added to the Key restriction. For example, "file://path/to/" should be formatted as "__file_url__/path/to/*". After enabling file:// referers, it is recommended you regularly check your usage, to make sure it matches your expectations`

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key#key-restrictions