# Referer Not Allowed Map Error

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a file in my pc named "GMPos.html", the file contains 1 marker:

```
 <script src='https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.4&key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

var icon_shadow = new google.maps.MarkerImage('icons/mm_20_shadow.png',
new google.maps.Size(28,22),
new google.maps.Point(0,0),
new google.maps.Point(10,21));
var a_icon = new google.maps.MarkerImage('icons/mm_20_red.png',
new google.maps.Size(22,22),
new google.maps.Point(0,0));
var map;

function loadMap() {
var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(14.60192,-90.53268);
var myOptions = {
center: myLatLng,
zoom: 12,
mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), myOptions);
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
position: myLatLng,
icon: a_icon,
shadow: icon_shadow,
map: map,
title:'Id: GUA001'
});
}

</script>
```

When I try to open the file in Firefox, I got the following error:

> "Google Maps API error: Google Maps API error:
>   RefererNotAllowedMapError
>   https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#referer-not-allowed-map-error
>   Your site URL to be authorized: file:///C:/RunTime/Mss/GMH/GMPos.html"

So, I have added the following referres:

```
*C:/RunTime/Mss*
file:///C:/RunTime/Mss/GMH/GMPos.html
*file:///C:/RunTime/Mss/GMH/GMPos.html*
```

But still throws the same error, please help.

Thank you in advance

Comment: There is a good chance that the Google APIs won't allow you to use file locations as URLs. You'll probably need to setup a local server.

Comment: Relevant: [Referer HTTP header](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referer)

Comment: related issue in the issue tracker: [Issue 9991: Google Maps API error: MissingKeyMapError when loading from file://](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=9991)

Comment: Thank you All for the information...

Comment: You can find answer regarding file:/ authorization here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35266644/using-google-map-javascript-library-with-cordova

Answer (score 3):

Please check your API quota restrictions connected to your key in the Google API Console. The marker API is considered a "Maps JavaScript API" restriction.